# If I add a new user to my sharepoint site as contributor, do I need to recrawl?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have a sharepoint 2007 site. If I add a new user to either my custom contributor or Reader groups of site, I need to re-crawl the content in order for them to see the search results.

Is it normal behavior ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal. Essentially, when the SharePoint search performs a crawl, it keeps track of the document, and who has permissions to the document. When permissions change, the search index isn't updated until another crawl is performed.

See the "content crawling" section of this article.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa981314.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you add them to an existing group, then you won't have to recrawl because the security descriptor has already been calculated.  However, if you give them unique access then it hasn't been calculated yet and won't show until the next incremental crawl.